# AdMob não funciona

Tags: android, admob

sou iniciante, criei um activity a partir do android studio, entao usando o id teste tudo funciona normal. quando insiro meu id do admob as propagandas nao aparecem, ja buildei o apk assinado e nada acontece. Tenho que publicar no google play para funcionar ?

Comment: Pra teste não precisa publicar, mas pra começar a aparecer as propagandas é necessário publicar sim, depois ir no site do admob e o localizar o aplicativo colocado na loja.

Comment: entendi. obrigado murilo estava preocupado procurei em todo canto. vou publicar primeiro então .vlw

Comment: coloquei o app na loja, e nao apareceu o banner, estranho que com o id de teste funciona bem e com meu id nao aparece nada, ja criei outro anuncio e tbm nao funcionou . procurei em tudo na internet e nao achei nada sobre . alguem pfv me salva.

Comment: Leva um certo tempo, cmg demorou uns 3 dias só para meu app depois de publicado fosse mostrado no admob

Comment: PROBLEMA  RESOLVIDO ; eu não tinha preenchido os dados de pagamento da conta por isso estavam barrando na mesma hora liberaram os anúncios. obrigado aos que tentaram ajudar.